# Measure to capture within-chain fluctuations in MCMC?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gibbs, traceplots

I am using two kinds of updates for a particular parameter in MCMC estimation of my model.

First update gives the following trace plot:

[image: MH update]

Second update gives the following trace plot:

[image: Gibbs sampling (conditional) update]

Note that the acceptance densities are slightly different in the two kinds of updates.

As you can see, the trace plot for the second type of update fluctuates much more. I wonder whether there is a "measure" that captures this fluctuation. Both chains end up having the same mean and STD, so those don't help. Is there something I could measure in order to keep track of this kind of within-chain fluctuation?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This looks like something that might show up in an ACF plot – in the first plot it looks like there could be positive correlation among consecutive draws.

Comment: Effective sample size?

Comment: @JamesOtto Ah you're right. The first update involves Metropolis-Hastings, so there definitely is a correlation among consecutive draws. I guess I could use ACF as a measure to differentiate between the two. Thanks.

Comment: @Xi'an I just understood the concept of effective sample size; I think that might be a good measure for this sort of thing. Thanks!